# MVC3 Models with repeating fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How do you handle views that are strongly typed to models with repeating fields in MVC3?  I would like to use the standard MVC3 methods of validation and use the HTML helper methods for generating inputs but have had to fall back on hand coding the inputs in HTML and using FormCollection for params in the controller method.

The representation of the email[] field in the view is basically a repeating text input 
(the user can click a button to add a new field).  For existing emails (update view) it needs to pass the id and the address string.  I have this working but it doesn't feel right at all.

```
public class Email
{
    public int EmailId
    public string EmailAddress
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required")]
    public string FirstName;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required")]
    public string LastName;

    // how to handle this?
    public Email[] EmailAddresses;
}
```

Comment: I assume it doesn't feel right because you're missing the declarative validation?  Methinks you're going to have to write your own validation attribute(s).

Comment: On the only MVC3 project I've worked on we have a collection of custom validators at every end point and all params are validated there by their corresponding validator in addition to whatever happens on the UI end.

Comment: @jonnyGold - "doesnt feel right" in that I'm doing validation, writing out of inputs and passing of args to controller method manually and not leveraging the features of the framework

Answer (score 1):

This can be a really lengthy post how to accomplish this.  But there are several blogs that discuss how this can be done:

http://blog.codeville.net/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

and

http://zahidadeel.blogspot.com/2011/05/master-detail-form-in-aspnet-mvc-3-i.html

HTH

Comment: Neither of those articles talk about validation. [This one](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) does, though.